# How to do nested iterations in jade?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, pug

```
ul
    li
        a(href='') menu1
    li
        a(href='') menu2
        ul
            li
                a(href='') sub-menu2
    li
        a(href='') menu3
        ul
            li
                a(href='') sub-menu3
                ul
                    li
                        a(href='') secondary-submenu3
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve, instead of writing the above jade code I want to be able to generate it using loops.
I tried the jade documentation, the examples show only one level of loop. For eg. I could try this

```
-var menus = [ 'menu1', 'menu2', 'menu3' ];
ul
    each menu in menus
        li
            a(href='') #{menu}
```

But this is not enough. if I try this

```
-var submenus = [ 'sub-menu1', 'sub-menu2', 'sub-menu3' ];
ul
    each menu in menus
        li
            a(href='') #{menu}
            ul
                each submenu in submenus
                li
                    a(href='') #{submenu}
```

this might work if each menu item had equal number of submenu items.
But in my case number of submenu item differs for each menu item.
How do i go around this?
How to do nested iterations in jade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need a object for this structure, for instance:

locals:

```
{
  menus: {
    m1: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    m2: ['x', 'y', 'z'],
    m3: ['i', 'ii']
  }
}
```

then you can use this template:

```
ul
  each menuKey in Object.keys(menus)
    - menu = menus[menuKey]
    li
      a(href='')=menuKey
        ul
          each submenu in menu
            li
              a(href='') #{submenu}
```

you can try this on this site: http://jade-lang.com/demo/
copy paste the template to the top left, and the locals to the top right textarea.

Comment: Thta is just splendid!..Thank you very much.