# Bootstrap menu dropdown level in pug

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I am trying to pass to bootstrap navbar an array in jade.

I already did this achievement:

```
block linkSelected
  -var selected = 'index';
 -var menu = { 'Sobre': '/sobre', 'blog': '/blog', 'Contato': '/contato' };
```

and in header:

```
#navbarCollapse.collapse.navbar-collapse
    ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
      each val, key in menu
        if selected === key
          li.nav-item.active
            a.nav-link(href=val, title=key)= key
        else
          li.nav-item
            a.nav-link(href=val+'.html', title=key)= key
```

So i ended up to this in menu:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <li class="nav-item"><a href="/sobre.html" title="Sobre" class="nav-link">Sobre</a></li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a href="/blog.html" title="blog" class="nav-link">blog</a></li>
   <li class="nav-item"><a href="/contato.html" title="Contato" class="nav-link">Contato</a></li>
</ul>
```

Does anyone know in pug/jade how to achieve the dropdown menu? I only achieved the first level menu... :/

Thank you so much and Happy New Year!

Comment: Please check similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28615164/how-to-do-nested-iterations-in-jade)